Question about monogenic extension.
Let $A$ be a DVR with fraction field $K$ (let's say it's a global field for simplicity). Let $L/K$ be a finite (separable) extension, and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Must $B=A[\beta]$ for some $\beta \in B$?
I know this is far from true if $A$ is not a DVR; in fact, $B$ may not even be a free $A$-module (ex: $A = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pq})}, B =  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q})}$)
But when $A$ is a DVR I'm not sure whether this is true or false. I know this is true if $B$ is a DVR and the extension $B/\mathfrak{q}$ over $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is separable. By Nakayama's lemma, if $A[\alpha] + \mathfrak{p}B = B$ then $A[\alpha] = B$

The answer is no.
user8268's argument in here works with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$; note to self: factors of $\mathbb{Q}_2[x]/(f)$ as an finite etale $\mathbb{Q}_2$-algebra correspond to places which correspond to primes lying over $(2)$.
See Milne ANT 2-6 for another counterexample with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$.
